# Reciprocal Dyadics: Menzel's Mathematical Physics

Tags: tensor-calculus

I am having difficulty justifying a step in Menzel's development of sets of reciprocal spanning vector sets.  Here's an abbreviated development.  All Fraktur letters represent vectors.

Introduce the dyadic

$\Phi=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}+a_{12}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{j}}}+a_{13}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{k}}}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\\
+a_{21}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{i}}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{j}}}+a_{22}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{j}}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{j}}}+a_{23}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{k}}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{j}}}\\
+a_{31}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{i}}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{k}}}}+a_{32}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{j}}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{k}}}}+a_{33}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{k}}}}\hat{\mathfrak{\mathfrak{k}}}
\end{bmatrix}=\mathfrak{B}_{1}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\hat{\mathfrak{j}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\hat{\mathfrak{k}}$

where

$\mathfrak{B}_{1}=\hat{\mathfrak{i}}a_{11}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}a_{21}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}a_{31}=\Phi\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{i}}$

$\mathfrak{B}_{2}=\hat{\mathfrak{i}}a_{12}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}a_{22}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}a_{32}=\Phi\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{i}}$

$\mathfrak{B}_{3}=\hat{\mathfrak{i}}a_{13}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}a_{22}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}a_{33}=\Phi\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{i}}$

I interpret this as

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{\mathfrak{i}} & \hat{\mathfrak{j}} & \hat{\mathfrak{k}}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathfrak{B}_{1} & \mathfrak{B}_{2} & \mathfrak{B}_{2}\end{array}\right]$

Introduce the identity dyadic

$\mathfrak{I}=\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}\hat{\mathfrak{j}}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}\mathfrak{\hat{\mathfrak{k}}}$

Define the reciprocal dyadic as

$\Phi^{-1}=\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}\mathfrak{b^{3}}$

$\Phi\cdot\Phi^{-1}=\mathfrak{I}$

Expand the dot product

$\Phi\cdot\Phi^{-1}=\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{b^{3}}\\=\begin{bmatrix}\mathfrak{b^{1}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}+\mathfrak{b^{1}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}+\mathfrak{b^{1}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\\
+\mathfrak{b^{2}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}+\mathfrak{b^{2}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}+\mathfrak{b^{2}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\\
+\mathfrak{b^{3}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}+\mathfrak{b^{3}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\mathfrak{\hat{k}}}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}+\mathfrak{b^{3}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}
\end{bmatrix}\\=\Phi^{-1}\cdot\Phi=\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}\hat{\mathfrak{j}}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}\mathfrak{\hat{\mathfrak{k}}}=\mathfrak{I}$

The first equivalence makes sense to me based on the orthonormality of the basis
$\{\hat{\mathfrak{i}},\hat{\mathfrak{j}},\hat{\mathfrak{k}}\}$.

$\Phi\cdot\Phi^{-1}=(\mathfrak{B}_{1}\hat{\mathfrak{i}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\hat{\mathfrak{j}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\hat{\mathfrak{k}})\cdot(\hat{\mathfrak{i}}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\hat{\mathfrak{j}}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\hat{\mathfrak{k}}\mathfrak{b^{3}})\\=\begin{bmatrix}\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{b^{3}}\\
+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{b^{3}}\\
+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\cdot\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{b^{3}}
\end{bmatrix}\\=\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{b^{3}}$

The next equivalence doesn't appear to be generally true. That is, without already assuming the mutual orthogonality of the 
 $\hat{\mathfrak{B}_{i}}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{b}}^{j}$ the equivalence cannot be assumed.

$\mathfrak{B}\mathfrak{b^{1}}+\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{b^{2}}+\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{b^{3}}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathfrak{b^{1}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}+\mathfrak{b^{1}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}+\mathfrak{b^{1}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\\
+\mathfrak{b^{2}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}+\mathfrak{b^{2}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}+\mathfrak{b^{2}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\\
+\mathfrak{b^{3}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{1}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{\hat{i}}+\mathfrak{b^{3}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{2}\mathfrak{\mathfrak{\hat{k}}}\mathfrak{\hat{j}}+\mathfrak{b^{3}}\cdot\mathfrak{B}_{3}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}\mathfrak{\hat{k}}
\end{bmatrix}$

It appears that Menzel is assuming the conclusion as part of its proof.  Am I missing something?

Comment: IMHO: this question would be a lot easier to read if your vectors were just in bold...

Comment: Numrok I follow Hermann Weyl, et al., in the use of Fraktur.  If you have ever read a book originally written in German and translated into English by converting from Fraktur to some allegedly distinguishable Latin font, you would appreciate my stubbornness in this matter.  Sure, it can be difficult at times to identify a particular character in a given font variant, but Futhark expands the available character set dramatically.  It can also be difficult to maintain consistent font weight when using an editor such as Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it.  Menzel didn't spell it all the way out, but provides sufficient motivation to conclude that the dyadic dot-product is associative.  Using the following, and assuming Einstein summation convention.

$\mathfrak{A}=a^{ij}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}$

$\mathfrak{B}=b^{ij}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}$

$\mathfrak{C}=c^{ij}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}$

$\mathfrak{D}=d^{ij}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}$

$\mathfrak{A}\cdot\mathfrak{B}\cdot\mathfrak{C}=a^{ij}b^{kl}c^{mn}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{j}\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{k}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{l}\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{m}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{n}=\mathfrak{D}$

$=a^{ij}b^{kl}c^{mn}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\delta_{jk}\delta_{lm}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{n}$

$=a^{ij}b^{kl}c^{mn}\delta_{jk}\delta_{lm}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{n}$

$=d^{in}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{n}$

The associativity of dyadic dot products follows from that of basic algebra.  It also shows that the result is again a dyadic.  The expression $\Phi\cdot\Phi^{-1}=\Phi^{-1}\cdot\Phi$ then follows trivial from the definition of the dyadic reciprocal. Working from right to left in the problematic equation justifies the second equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints and comments that may or may not amount to an answer:

1. $b^1, b^2, b^3$ are not defined a priori. You are rather *choosing* them *such that* $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\phi$. So you are not assuming mutual orthogonality of the $b$s with the $B$, you are imposing it and showing that this is indeed necessary to obtain the inverse.
2. At this point it is useful to take a step back and ask what you are actually doing: you are inverting a matrix and you put a lot of fancy fraktur letters on it. The "orthonormality" is saying the column vectors of the matrix are reciprocal to the inverse matrices row vectors and vice versa.